# FlashAir API document for Android dev

Tags: android, flashair

I have toshiba FlashAir SD card. I want to make an android app for it but i don't have programming information.
Do you know where is the API document?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the API guide:
https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/

Also, here are some Android tutorials for FlashAir development:
https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/android/